# How to make the IDE recognize that I have jquery included in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, ide

I have a little problem. 
I am including the jquery.min.js file as a script in my HTML file, but I want to use the jquery functions in a seperate .js file. In a situation like this the IDEs like PhpStorm or Visual Studio 2013 won't recognize that the jquery.min.js has been included in the HTML file. My problem with this is that VS won't autocomplete the jQuery functions that I use, and sometimes PhpStorm will have a problem with this as well. Of course the code will work when I test it in a browser, but I would like to have some syntax highlighting and autocompletion as well.
How can I state it to the IDE that I've included the needed jQuery file in my HTML page so that it will start recognizing the syntax and help me with autocompletion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can define reference path of your jquery.min.js on top of your .JS file. Also you can just drag and drop the jquery source file to your seperate .JS file and Visual Studio will automatically generate the reference path for you.

```
/// <reference path="Libraries/jquery.min.js" />
//rest of your code starts
```